# Creating a dynamic popup for Disqus comments for different threads

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, uniqueidentifier, disqus

Edit: It seems Disqus is using the current page URL as the comment thread identifier despite me being explicit and stating:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var disqus_developer = 1;
    var disqus_identifier = "@Model.UniqueThreadIdentifier"; <--- HERE
    var disqus_shortname = 'foo';

    /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
    (function () {
        var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
        dsq.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
    })();
</script>
```

Read below for more details.

---

Disqus says that I can identify a "page" with a unique identifier.

Now in this particular page there are about 10 items and I'd like each item to have a personal Disqus discussion thread.

So here's the actual page that gets loaded:

```
@foreach (var strong in Model.StrongAgainst)
{
    <div class="pick">        
            <div class="actions">
                <a href="#modalDialogue" data-toggle="modal" 
                   id="@strong.UniqueThreadIdentifier" class="btn btn-comment">
                    <i class="icon-comment"></i>
                    999
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
}
```

That `@UniqueThreadIdentifier` is what I'm using to let Disqus load the appropriate thread.

Next, in that same HTML view, I have this Javascript line, which using the UniqueIdentifier returns a PartialView with the appropriate Disqus configuration and HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on("click", "#strong-against .pick .data .actions .btn-comment", function () {
            var commentUniqueVar = $(this).attr("id");
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Counterpicks/GetCommentThread',
                data: { uniqueidentifier: commentUniqueVar },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#strongAgainstCommentModal').html(data);
                    alert("Finished loading.");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

And up to here it's 100% confirmed that the right values are being loaded into the HTML.

Here is the PartialView:

```
<div class="modal-body">    
    <div id="disqus_thread">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var disqus_developer = 1;
        var disqus_identifier = "@Model.UniqueThreadIdentifier";
        var disqus_shortname = 'foobar';

        /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
        (function () {
            var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
            dsq.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
            (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
        })();
    </script>
    <noscript>
        Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="http://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments
            powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
    <a href="http://disqus.com" class="dsq-brlink">blog comments powered by <span class="logo-disqus">
        Disqus</span></a>    
</div>
```

Notice how I set the `disqus_identifier` using a strongly typed model with the correct value.

My only guess is that when declaring a variable like that, it's created globally? (I think?) And the Disque javascript library is always going to use the first value I assigned to it. Correct?

How can I appropriately load the correct identifier to the Disqus javascript library?

Answer (score 0):

What the identifier allows you to do is display the same thread on multiple URLs, but you can't display multiple threads on the same URL using a new identifier alone (this is a common misconception). We developed a method for reloading a thread with AJAX called Disqus.Reset, which is documented here: http://docs.disqus.com/help/85/

You can also hack it without Disqus.Reset, and that's demonstrated on this post: http://collaborable.com/blog/disqus-jquery-hack-awesome-ux